# Executing docker command from a remote machine

Tags: java, docker, remote-access

I have a requirement where I need to execute some docker commands from a remote machine.

I am using java ssh library to connect to the machine where I need to execute the docker commands, and then trying to execute the command.

The actual docker command is:

```
docker exec -it idaas_webtier_1 /bin/bash
_tadm1="${OTD_HOME}/bin/tadm"
_tadm2="--user=${OTD_ADMIN_USER} --password-file=${OTD_ADMIN_PWD} --host=${HOSTNAME} --port=${OTD_ADMIN_PORT} --no-prompt --accept-cert"
$_tadm1 pull-config $_tadm2 --config=${OTD_CONFIG_NAME} ${HOSTNAME}
$_tadm1 create-origin-server-pool $_tadm2 --type=http --config=${OTD_CONFIG_NAME} --origin-server=server.us.oracle.com:7001 qaverify-server-pool
$_tadm1 set-health-check-prop $_tadm2 --config=${OTD_CONFIG_NAME} --origin-server-pool=qaverify-server-pool request-method=GET request-uri=/
$_tadm1  create-route $_tadm2 --config=${OTD_CONFIG_NAME} --vs=${OTD_CONFIG_NAME} --origin-server-pool=qaverify-server-pool --condition="\$uri=~\"/testApp.*\"" qaverify-route
$_tadm1 deploy-config $_tadm2 --restart ${OTD_CONFIG_NAME}
exit
```

When trying remotely, I added the actual values for the variables and put it in a shell script and executing the sh script, but it executes only the first line
The script is as below

```
docker exec -it idaas_webtier_1 /bin/bash
_tadm1=/scratch/oracle/otd/bin/tadm
_tadm2="--user=admin --password-file=/scratch/oracle/otd/password-file --host=admin-server.cloudgate.dev.oraclecloud.local --port=8989 --no-prompt --accept-cert"
$_tadm1 pull-config $_tadm2 --config=idcs-config admin-server.cloudgate.dev.oraclecloud.local
$_tadm1 create-origin-server-pool $_tadm2 --type=http --config=idcs-config --origin-server=adc6260266.us.oracle.com:7001 qaverify-server-pool
$_tadm1 set-health-check-prop $_tadm2 --config=idcs-config --origin-server-pool=qaverify-server-pool request-method=GET request-uri=/
$_tadm1  create-route $_tadm2 --config=idcs-config --vs=idcs-config --origin-server-pool=qaverify-server-pool --condition="\$uri=~\"/testApp.*\"" qaverify-route
$_tadm1 deploy-config $_tadm2 --restart idcs-config
exit
```

It executes only the first line and not the rest.

If I add `'|'` to the commands as:

```
docker exec -it idaas_webtier_1 /bin/bash | _tadm1=/scratch/oracle/otd/bin/tadm
```

It says:

> _tadm1=/scratch/oracle/otd/bin/tadm: Command not found.

Any pointer on this would help.

Answer (score 0):

U could write a shell script and directly run the script instead of accessing the bash terminal.
Eg.,
`docker exec -it idaas_webtier_1 tadm.sh`

Comment: U could also ignore -t when u need tht to be executed without any terminal  [docker exec -i idaas_webtier_1 tadm.sh]